# Solve conflict shift/reduce with simple calculator grammar

Tags: bison, yacc

Hello I have just started doing some parsing in bison/yacc. Now my first program already fails. What went wrong? I am using an example from:
[original source of tutorial](http://epaperpress.com/lexandyacc/pry1.html)

```
%{
    #include <stdio.h>
    int yylex(void);
    void yyerror(char *);
%}


%token INTEGER

%%

program:
        program expr '\n'         { printf("%d\n", $2); }
        | 
        ;

expr:
        INTEGER                   { $$ = $1; }
        | expr '+' expr           { $$ = $1 + $3; }
        | expr '-' expr           { $$ = $1 - $3; }
        ;

%%

void yyerror(char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", s);
}

int main(void) {
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}
```

Using version 2.4.1 of bison I get this error:

```
conflicts: 4 shift/reduce
```

Comment: [AIX Documentation of yacc](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.genprogc%2Fdoc%2Fgenprogc%2Fie_prog_4lex_yacc.htm) Explaints my problem. My grammar is ambigous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
expr:
    INTEGER                   { $$ = $1; }
    | expr '+' INTEGER           { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | expr '-' INTEGER           { $$ = $1 - $3; }
```

bison/yacc don't like right recursion. If the input is `1+2+3`, when the parser reaches `1+2+` it can't decide either to reduce `1+2` to `expr` or to shift another token in order to reduce `2+3` to `expr`. By specifying `INTEGER` on the right, it can decide to reduce as soon as it sees `1+2` leaving only `expr + 3` then reducing again.

You can also solve the issue by specifying that `+` and `-` are left associative, thus giving a higher priority to reducing `1+2` over shifting new tokens. Add that line in your preamble:

```
%left '+' '-'
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I had just figured it out by myself. It makes things even more clear to me.

Comment: Bison has no problem with right recursion. If you wanted a right-associative `=` operator, you could use `expr : INTEGER '=' expr;`; that's fine. The problem is when you have `expr` on *both* sides; then the grammar is ambiguous. As you say, you can resolve the ambiguity with precedence declarations.

Comment: "Not liking right-recursion" is irrelevant here.  They support both, but prefer left-recursion when stack space is a concern (not the case here).  The problem here is that the grammar is ambiguous, and does not say if "1-2-3" is "(1-2)-3" or "1-(2-3)".  Of course, `%left '-'` is the right to do, but it has nothing to do with Bison's liking it or not.

Comment: I remarked the OP was "starting" to use yacc and I said 'like' to try to give him a simple rule to follow which would work in 90% of all use cases.